# Relating items between 2 arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

**EDIT:**
Might be pretty easy but I'm struggling to get this right. How do I loop through 2 arrays to relate 1st item to 1st and second item to 2nd, etc...?

I'm trying to trigger "a" when "abc" is called and trigger "b" when "zxy" is called

```
var a = ["a", "b"],
    b = ["abc", "xyz"];

for(i=0;i<a.length;i++){
        html2canvas(b[i]).then(function(canvas) {
           var logcvs=document.createElement('canvas');
           logcvs.id=a[i]; 
           alert(a[i]) // I want "a" to popup once and "b" once to popup once
        }
}
```

Comment: Can you be more accurate please, what do you mean by `trigger` and `"abc" is called`? I see no events, no functions in the above code.

Comment: @skobaljic: thanks. See my edit. Basically I'm looking to get "a" to popup once and "b" once to popup once when I do `alert(a[i]) ` inside within `html2canvas(b[i]).then(function(canvas) { ... }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your array keys/indexes are fine, the problem is **the scope of variable `i`**. In order to create a scope you have to create a function (there is no loop-variable-scope in Javascript):

```
var a = ["a", "b"],
    b = ["abc", "xyz"];

function createCanvas(i) {
    /* i may have value of 1 here */
    html2canvas(b[i]).then(function(canvas) {
       var logcvs=document.createElement('canvas');
       logcvs.id=a[i];  /* i is still 1 here, no changes */
    }
};

for(i=0;i<a.length;i++){
    createCanvas(i);
}
```

In the near future we shall be able to use [block-scope-variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let).

> **let** allows you to declare variables that are limited in scope to the
>   block, statement, or expression on which it is used. This is unlike
>   the **[var](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var)** keyword, which defines a variable globally, or locally to an
>   entire function regardless of block scope.

Your code would simply become:

```
var a = ["a", "b"],
    b = ["abc", "xyz"];

for(i=0;i<a.length;i++){
    let j=i; /* Here declare the block-scope-variable */
    html2canvas(b[j]).then(function(canvas) {
       var logcvs=document.createElement('canvas');
       logcvs.id=a[j]; 
       alert(a[j]);
    }
}
```

Note: It is still **not** supported by all browsers.

Comment: thanks. Looks good. Is't it possible to do something like `var x = i` just after `html2canvas(b[i]).then(function(canvas, i) {`  and use the `x` as the current value? I have tried and failed but why is it not possible?

Comment: Because you are still in global scope, at the end of `for` loop the `x` will get last value (in example code **1**). The returning function is a [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) and is asynchronous - in time it executes the global variable `x` will always be **1** (`a.length-1`). But if you call the function with parameter `i`, the scope of that variable is now within the function, so you can use it after you get the promise.

Comment: I'm sure this scope of variable solution will be used throughout my life... :)

Comment: I see your edit... that's exactly what I was referring to in my first comment. Thanks again for the additional info.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really get what your intention is but I think this might solve your problem.

Just store the values in an object like this:

```js
var newObject = {
  a: "abc",
  b: "xyz"
}
```

You are now able to do things like this:

```js
var newObject = {
  a: "abc",
  b: "xyz"
}

function fu(bar){
  alert(newObject[bar]);
}

fu("a");
fu("b");
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that you are creating a function in each iteration of the `for` loop, you have to change your code to be a function call instead :

```js
     var a = ["a", "b"],
     b = ["abc", "xyz"];
  
     // create the function here to accept a generic params    
     html2canvas = function(e1, e2) {    
       for(i=0;i<e1.length;i++){
          if(i<=e2.length) {
             var logcvs=document.createElement('canvas');
             logcvs.id=e2[i];
             document.body.appendChild(logcvs);
             alert(e2[i]) ;
          } else {
             break;
          }
        }
           
     }
     
     //Call the function here
     html2canvas(b, a);
```